# InactiveRpcError error when python client tries to use grpc service with TLS

Tags: python, c++, ssl, grpc

I'm using grpc between a c++ server and python client. An unsecure connection works fine, but when switching to TLS I can't get the python client to connect to the server. When the python client tries to use a grpc service, I get the error, InactiveRpcError StatusCode.UNNAVAILABLE "failed to connect to all addresses".

To generate my certs I'm using:

```
# Generate valid CA
openssl genrsa -passout pass:XXX -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:XXX -new -x509 -days 1000 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=A/ST=B/L=C/O=D/OU=E/CN=Root CA"

# Generate valid Server Key/Cert
openssl genrsa -passout pass:XXX -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:XXX -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=A/ST=B/L=C/O=D/OU=E/CN=localhost"
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:XXX -days 1000 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

# Remove passphrase from the Server Key
openssl rsa -passin pass:XXX -in server.key -out server.key 

# Generate valid Client Key/Cert
openssl genrsa -passout pass:XXX -des3 -out client.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:XXX -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=A/ST=B/L=C/O=D/OU=E/CN=localhost"
openssl x509 -passin pass:XXX -req -days 1000 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

# Remove passphrase from Client Key
openssl rsa -passin pass:XXX -in client.key -out client.key
```

Then to start the c++ server I use

```
grpc:ServerBuilder builder;

std::ifstream ca_strm("ca.crt")
std::stringstream ca_ss;
ca_ss << ca_strm.rdbuf();

std::ifstream crt_strm("server.crt")
std::stringstream crt_ss;
crt_ss << crt_strm.rdbuf();

std::ifstream key_strm("server.key")
std::stringstream key_ss;
key_ss << key_strm.rdbuf();

grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair pkcp;
pkcp.private_key = key_ss.str();
pkcp.cert_chain = crt_strm.str();

grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;
ssl_opts.pem_root_certs=ca_ss.str();
ssl_opts.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back(pkcp);

std::shared_ptr<grpc::ServerCredentials> creds;
creds = grpc::SslSeverCredentials(ssl_opts);

builder->AddListeningPort("localhost:5000", creds);

//register services
//start grpc server
```

And finally, the python client code is

Python client

```
inFile = open("ca.crt", "rb")
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(inFile.read())
channel = grpc.secure_channel("localhost:5000", creds, options=(('grpc.enable_http_proxy', 0),))
stub = foo_pb2_grpc.FooStub(channel)
stub.FooService()
```

I'm not really clear which file I'm supposed to be reading in on the python client when creating the credentials, though I've tried all of them and all give the same error.